# Change '\\' to '\' in bytes object type in python

Tags: python, string, object, byte

I am confused with the usage of the bytes object type in Python. I am reading a Txt file that comprises 4 bytes of hex values in each row. For example one of my rows consists of hex values `81c50400`. I want to manipulate this value to `\x81\xc5\x04\x00`.

However, with the bytes object type I am getting the values as `\\x81\\xc5\\x04\\x00`. I have provided the details of my experiment below.

```
with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
    words = file.readlines()
    word_count = len(word)
    for i in range(word_count):
      byte_to_txr = r'\x' + str(words[i])
      print(bytes(byte_to_send, encoding = 'utf-8'))
```

The result is printed as:

```
\\x81
\\xc5
\\x04
\\x00
```

What is the mistake I committed here?

As it should print `\x81\xc5 ...`

Comment: Are you asking about why the single backslash is escaped or are you asking how to print on a single line with multiple print statements?

Comment: No, I am not trying to print the values. Actually, I had digital hardware and I am trying to send some packets to the hardware in hex. I want it to be \x81. However, with encoding it was converted to \\x81 and the hardware was interpreting it as something else. My question is is there a real difference between \x81 and \\x81. Is there a better way to encode it?

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desired values by:

```
import codecs
data = codecs.escape_decode('\\x81\\xc5\\x04\\x00')
print(data)

#output
(b'\x81\xc5\x04\x00', 16)

print(data[0])
#output
b'\x81\xc5\x04\x00'
```

Or

```
d,y = codecs.escape_decode('\\x81\\xc5\\x04\\x00')
print(d)

#output
b'\x81\xc5\x04\x00'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. It worked for my purpose. Actually, I had digital hardware and I am trying to send some packets to the hardware in hex. I want it to be \x81. However, with encoding it was converted to \\x81 and the hardware was interpreting it as something else. My question is is there a real difference between \x81 and \\x81. Is there a better way to encode it?